# Unable to close file after writing it with data stream from Com port using python

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to open a serial port via Python, write the incoming data stream into a file and close the file when the data stream stops.

My program is unable to detect that the port is no longer receiving any data. So the file remains open. What do I do?

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(port='COM8', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N',  stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=0, rtscts=0)
print("Connected to Audio(COM8) port") 
try:
   f = open('C:\Users\user\Desktop\final.raw', 'w')
   while 1:
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    if ser_bytes:
        f.write(ser_bytes)
    else:
        break      
finally:
    f.close()
    print("output file closed")
    ser.close()
```

Comment: Do you need to flush the buffer before the stream is seen as closed?  Is there some command like ser.flush() you can do before f.close()?  You can also do f.flush() before f.close() to flush the file buffer.

Comment: Can you describe what series of events would lead the port to no longer receive data?

Is there a message that is transmitted over the wire to indicate that no future messages will be sent?

Do you simply want to close the file if no messages has been received for n seconds?

Comment: The Serial port is connected to a module with a sim. It streams data when it detects speech over the call. the data often looks like this '\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0' No particular message to indicate the end. Closing the file if no messages has been received for n seconds is something I can work with. How is that done?

Comment: See Lijo's answer. Simply add a timeout to you readline() call and that will be the achieved effect.

Answer (score 1):

Specify **timeout** while using `ser.readline()`

Comment: Just adding on to this.. if you don't specify a timeout and your device stops sending data, `ser.readline()` will cause an infinite loop so the rest of your code is never executed. For example when you initialize with `timeout=10`, `readline()` will wait to receive bytes of data for 10 seconds before determining a timeout has occurred.